# PYTHON/OUTLOOK Sending e-mails through PYTHON with DOCX

Tags: python, email, outlook

I have to send mails through python. It works. It is almost done. The only problem is that I have to keep the formatting too. So either I have to send e mail as HTML (and then rewrite template with html instead of .docx) OR copy .docx file with extension 
Anybody has any ideas how to do this? Thanks guys.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import fileinput as fi 
from docx import Document

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

path_in = 'maillist.csv'
input_file = open(path_in, 'r')
document = Document('template.docx')
document_html = open('template.html', 'r')

print(temp)
def filecount(fname):
        for line in fi.input(fname):
            pass
        return fi.lineno()

print("Total mails %s" % (filecount(path_in)))
count = 0
for line in input_file:
    if (count>16):
        name = line.split(";")[0]
        mail_adress = line.split(";")[1]
        subject = line.split(";")[2]
        print ("%s:%s:%s:" % (name, mail_adress, subject))
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = mail_adress
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.body = temp.replace("XXXNAMEXXX", name)
        mail.send
    else:
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.RTFBody` and/or `.HTMLBody` methods to the document objects :

```
    document = Document('template.docx').RTFBody
    document_html = open('template.html', 'r').HTMLBody
```

Also, I'm not sure if it makes much of a difference but, for convention's sake, I like to capitalize the first letter of the method for the `mailItem` object.

Let me know if that works.